# Missing len() within sqlite query

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py, typeerror

I have been messing around with trying to rank users by experience, although when call on the command rank, I seem to get a type error for a missing len()

error: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object of type 'sqlite3.Cursor' has no len()

I'm calling a help class (although this is also my first time using classes) and within it, it calls len which is giving me an error.

Thank you for all of the help!

```
class HelpMenu(ListPageSource):
    def __init__(self, ctx, data):
        self.ctx = ctx
        super().__init__(data, per_page = 10)

    async def write_page(self, menu, fields=[]):
         offset = (menu.current_page * self.per_page) + 1
         len_data = len(self.entries)

         embed = Embed(title="Server XP Leaderboard",
                       colour=self.ctx.author.colour)
         embed.set_thumbnail(url = self.ctx.guild.icon_url)
         embed.set_footer(text = f"{offset:,} - {min(len_data, offset+self.per_page-1):,} of {len_data:, } members.")

         for name, value in fields:
             embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=False)
         return embed

    async def format_page(self, menu, entries):
        fields = []

        for idx, entry in enumerate(entries):
            fields.append(("Ranks", "\n".join(f'{idx}. {entry[0]} (XP: {entry[1]} | Level: {entry[2]})')))

            return await self.write_page(menu, fields)


class Exp(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @command(aliases = ['lvl', 'level'])
    async def rank(self, ctx):

        db = sqlite3.connect('xpdata.db')
        cursor = db.cursor()

        # user_id = self.author.id
        guild_id = ctx.guild.id
        #
        # cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM xpdata WHERE user_id = {user_id}  AND guild_id = {guild_id}')
        # for row in cursor.fetchall():
        #     level_display = row[3]

        xp_ranking = cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_id, xp, level FROM xpdata WHERE guild_id = {guild_id} ORDER BY xp DESC')

        #menu
        ranking_menu = MenuPages(source=HelpMenu(ctx, xp_ranking))
        await ranking_menu.start(ctx)

        #await ctx.channel.send('{} is currently level {} and rank {}'.format(ctx.author.mention, level_display))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't fetch the queried results.

Correct this line:

```py
 xp_ranking = cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_id, xp, level FROM xpdata WHERE guild_id = {guild_id} ORDER BY xp DESC')
```

to

```py
cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_id, xp, level FROM xpdata WHERE guild_id = {guild_id} ORDER BY xp DESC')
xp_ranking = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: @Barmar Oh yes, you'r right. I wanted to be smart in one line... bad idea -.- (I edited my post)

Comment: Unfortunately, fluent interfaces aren't the norm in Python.